# i cannot understand why i get string when use * and list when not in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, args

In Python i am creating a classmethod and i am using a classmethod to get my parameters from a string by spliting it i am getting what i want but cannot understand why i get a list when i am not using * and not getting list when using *. here's my code below.

```
 @classmethod
 def from_one_str(cls, onestr):
    print(*onestr.split(",")) # getting two string

 # on running this is result - John C++

    print(onestr.split(",")) # getting a list of two strings
 # on running this is result - ['John', 'C++']

 # This is what i am running - John = Programmer.from_one_str("John,C++")
```

Comment: Have you attempted to find out what the `*` is for? Why are you using it?

Comment: By putting the asterisk (*) you're unpacking a `list`

Answer (score 2):

[In a function call, the `*` operator unpacks the given list into separate arguments.](https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

```
print(*["John", "C++"])
```

is thus equivalent to

```
print("John", "C++")
```

To bring this back to your code:

```
def from_one_str(onestr):
    print(*onestr.split(","))
```

1. You call `from_one_str()` with the string `"John,C++"`
2. The string will be split by `"John,C++".split(",")` into `["John", "C++"]`
3. That list will be then spread to arguments for `print` by the `*` operator.
4. `print` prints each argument – `"John"` and `"C++"` – separated by space.
5. You see `John C++`.

Comment: ok it means * will convert that list in a tupple isn't it

Comment: No, that's not it. Read the linked documentation.

Comment: @FgrReloaded You confuse how * (and ** for that matter) works for function parameters (e.g. `def spam(*args, **kwargs):` and what it does in function calls e.g. `spam(*some_args)`.

Comment: I got it thanks man